# Wondering why dropIndex in mongodb is not working

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to drop an index that I have created in MongoDB. The code seems to be right and I am wondering where did I go wrong and I hope someone here could help.

The following are the data and the drop index command I have used. Thanks

```
db.stores.insertMany(
   [
     { _id: 1, name: "Java Hut", description: "Coffee and cakes" },
     { _id: 2, name: "Burger Buns", description: "Gourmet hamburgers" },
     { _id: 3, name: "Coffee Shop", description: "Just coffee" },
     { _id: 4, name: "Clothes Clothes Clothes", description: "Discount clothing" },
     { _id: 5, name: "Java Shopping", description: "Indonesian goods" }
   ]
)

db.stores.createIndex( { name: "text", description: "text" } )
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.stores.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "BioMedical.stores"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name_text_description_text",
                "ns" : "BioMedical.stores",
                "weights" : {
                        "description" : 1,
                        "name" : 1
                },
                "default_language" : "english",
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 3
        }
]

db.stores.dropIndex({name_text_description_text:1})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "can't find index with key: { name_text_description_text: 1.0 }",
        "code" : 27,
        "codeName" : "IndexNotFound"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/), if you are using the index name it needs to be given as the argument. Try:

```
db.stores.dropIndex('name_text_description_text')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and greatly appreciated.